# show that the matrix can not be the adjoint of any invertible matrix with real entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

> Show that the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1& 1\\0 &3 & 1\\0 & 2&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
> cannot be the adjoint of any invertible matrix with real entries.

im really stuck with this , is there any way?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Unfortunately, your post doesn’t fully meet this site’s policy (see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)). I recommend that you edit your post. (1) Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to type all your formulae instead of a lazy picture. (2) You should provide some context to your question. Where is this problem from? Why is it interesting and important? (3) Please tell in the post, did you try to solve it? What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?

Comment: What is your adjoint meant? Is it the adjugate of the matrix adj $A$ or the matrix of the adjoint operator?

Comment: yes adjugate of the matrix adjA

Comment: you should provide more 'your idea' on the question, otherwise this question would be closed. Do you have any thought arising from this question about adj like any identity or theorem you can use?

Comment: Hint: can you say anything about the determinant of an adjugate?